# Failed to instantiate file "default.master" from module "DefaultMasterPage": Source path "default.master" not found

Tags: sharepoint

I create site-definition using VS 2010 and set the master on onet.xml file as the follwing

```
 <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
      <!-- Publishing -->
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value="/_catalogs/masterpage/test.master"/>
        <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/default.aspx"/>
        <Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;"/>
        <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
        <!--<Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/"/>
        <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/"/>-->
        <Property Key="AlternateCssUrl" Value="" />
        <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
      </Properties>
    </Feature>
```

when i create site from this template  i get this error

Failed to instantiate file "default.master" from module "DefaultMasterPage": Source path "default.master" not found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the default.master file is at the masterpage library (http://[your
   site]/_catalogs/masterpage)
2. Ensure that the user that creates the site has access to the
   _catalogs/masterpage library.

   This can be done by creating the site with a user that is site
   collection admin or by explicitly give him permissions on that
   library.
3. Ensure that the default.master file is ghosted. This can be done using the stsadm -o gl-enumunghostedfiles command (http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/re-ghosting-pages/) available in the Gary Lapoint's stsadm extensions (http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/)

For more information about Sharepoint 2010 web templates:

1. http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Web-Templates-in-SharePoint-2010-What-You-Should-Know.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx

Comment: default.master is found and permissions is site collection admin but not work

Comment: Did you customize your default.master file (via sharepoint designer or other means) ? If this file is customized (unghosted) site creation will not work. Also, can you check your ULS logs for that error and see if it contains more information ?

Comment: Not customize but it is show updated by my user since creation the site and the log in the below answer

Comment: The problem still exists any help!!

Comment: Besides checking if the file is really ghosted via the gl-enumunghostedfiles command (sometimes files get unghosted accidentally) I can only recommend that you check your solution against the 2 links I just added above (the second one contains a sample VS project you can download). The error you mentioned is very generic, (as you can see by a basic google search for it), so it can have a lot of possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

http://seansharepoint.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/failed-to-instantiate-file.html

The name of template name and the deploy directory must be the same. If you rename your project or your template VS don't rename the deploy dir.

Regards.